# Trying to web scrape and its giving me back this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, web-scraping

My end result for the code is to have the user input an item and the code will pull back the first result from several different websites.
Right now, I'm not too far in and am unable to get the first website to pull back a result.

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/officeworks/search?q=charger'


#Open Collection
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close

#html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


#grabs each products
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",  {"class" : ""}) [1:]
 
for container in containers:
```

This is where the error is:

```
title_container = container.findAll('div', {'class' : 'sc-bdVaJa Tile-iqbpf7-0 jRikHh'} )
product_name = title_container[0].text


print (product_name)
```

Comment: You've chosen a dynamic page. The content you want comes from an additional POST search query you can find as `https://k535caawve-1.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20react-instantsearch%205.4.0%3B%20JS%20Helper%202.26.1&x-algolia-application-id=K535CAAWVE&x-algolia-api-key=8a831febe0110932cfa06ff0e2024b4f` in network tab.

Comment: Can you explain this further? it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: That page is being loaded by JavaScript. You need to use Selenium to scrape it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `title_container` has contents every time? If the error is thrown on line: `product_name = title_container[0].text` then that means that at least one container in containers returns an empty list when `container.findAll('div', {'class' : 'sc-bdVaJa Tile-iqbpf7-0 jRikHh'} )` is called and as a result when `roduct_name` is looked for at index 0 there is nothing there.

You could attempt to troubleshoot this by using an `if (len(title_container) != 0)` before `product_name` to figure out what type of item is giving you trouble but beyond that I believe your problem could be solved by checking each of your test cases to identify exactly which type of site is giving you trouble